# Dropzone js check for duplicate files using md5_file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.3, dropzone.js

Following is my code which upload files on server using dropzone.js plugin:

```
var file_up_names = new Array;
var duplicate_files = new Array;
var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var dropzone = $("#addPhotosForm").dropzone({
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFileConfirmation: "Do you want to remove this image?",
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drop images here to upload",
    dictRemoveFile: "Remove photo",
    init: function() {
      this.on("success", function(file, response) {
        if (response.status === 1) {
            file_up_names.push(response.filename);
            $(file.previewTemplate).append('<span class="server_file_path hide">' + response.newfilename + '</span>');
        } else if (response.status === 2) {
            duplicate_files.push(response.filename);
            this.removeFile(file);
        }
    }),
      this.on("queuecomplete", function() {
        var html = "Photos added successfully!";
        $('#photoUploadSuccess').html('');
        $('#photoUploadError').html('');
        $('#photoUploadSuccess').removeClass('hide');
        $('#photoUploadError').addClass('hide');
        if (file_up_names.length > 0) {
            if (duplicate_files.length > 0) {
                html += " Following photos are skipped as those are already uploaded.";
                html += "<ul>";
                for (var i = 0; i < duplicate_files.length; ++i) {
                    html += "<li>";
                    html += duplicate_files[i];
                    html += "</li>";
                }
                html += "</ul>";
            }
            $('#photoUploadSuccess').html(html);
        } else if (duplicate_files.length > 0 && file_up_names.length === 0) {
            html = "Following photos already exists. Please check to see if it already exists and try again.";
            html += "<ul>";
            for (var i = 0; i < duplicate_files.length; ++i) {
                html += "<li>";
                html += duplicate_files[i];
                html += "</li>";
            }
            html += "</ul>";
            $('#photoUploadSuccess').addClass('hide');
            $('#photoUploadError').removeClass('hide');
            $('#photoUploadError').html(html);
        } else {
            html = "Photos not uploaded!";
            $('#photoUploadSuccess').addClass('hide');
            $('#photoUploadError').removeClass('hide');
            $('#photoUploadError').html(html);
        }
        duplicate_files = [];
        file_up_names = [];
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#photoUploadSuccess').html('');
            $('#photoUploadError').html('');
            $('#photoUploadSuccess').addClass('hide');
            $('#photoUploadError').addClass('hide');
        }, 5000);
    }),
    this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
        var server_file = $(file.previewTemplate).children('.server_file_path').text();
        // Do a post request and pass this path and use server-side language to delete the file
        var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
            url: "{{ URL::route('removePhotos') }}",
            data: "file_name=" + server_file,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    })
}
});
```

While below is my server code which get file's md5 and store it on server and next time when user upload same image again it check in database and if same md5_file result found it won't allow to upload image. It work when i use simple form, but on dropzone it's not working:

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$md5_check = md5_file($tempFile);
//check if same image uploaded before
$duplicateCheck = Photos::where('userId', '=', $this->userId)->where('md5_check', '=', "$md5_check")->where('isDeleted', '=', 0)->count();
```

I've found that if I upload same images together it won't work and return count 0 from DB. But if I upload same images separately like for example upload image once it uploads, upload same image again it get count from DB and give message that image already there. Maybe it's due to dropzone asynchronous calls but can't figure it out how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you upload more than one image `$_FILES` contains an array of files, so you should cycle it with a `foreach` and do your operations inside that loop.

You can check what's happening when you upload more than 1 files by inserting this line of code:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Or if you want a result better readable:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($_FILES, true)."</pre>";
```

Check the structure of `$_FILES` when you upload more than 1 file, it should be an array of files.

Comment: I've checked that, when we upload two (or more) images dropzone send two different calls separately on server so that's why I don't have to loop on them.

Comment: What's the content of $_FILES when dropzone sends the data?

Comment: this is the content of $_FILES:   Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Screenshot (1) - Copy.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\phpABCC.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 316877
        )

)

Comment: Fixed it by using these two options:

autoProcessQueue: true
parallelUploads: 1